# Printing multiple newlines with Python

Tags: python, text, operating-system

I'm trying to separate some outputted text in Python 3.
Heres sorta an example of what iv got now

```
print("words")
print("")
print("")
print("")
print("")
print("")
print("")
 #(Print would keep going on like 50 times)...
print("more words")
```

now putting all those prints is annoying and i need the words to be vertically seperated. like this

```
words









more words
```

Any ideas on how to separate huge verticle distances.
Thanks :)

Comment: `print('\n' * 50)`

Comment: use `\n` . Ex : `print("words \n\n\n\n\n\n")` *OR* in your case `print('\n' * 50)`

Answer (score 2):

You could put a newline character "\n" in the string, e.g.

```
>>> print ("\n\n\n\n")
```

Characters preceded by a backslash are 'escaped', and are converted to special characters by Python. Some commonly used escape sequences are:

- Newline "\n"
- Tab     "\t"
- Carriage Return "\r"
- Backslash "\\"
- Hexadecimal character code "\x0f"
- Quote character "\"" or '\''

Note that strings can be repeated by multiplying them with a number, e.g.

```
>>> print ("\n" * 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a string of newline characters, which will result in vertical space, like this:

```
lines = 5  # Number of blank lines
print("\n" * lines)
```